# Android Studio ArrayList not filling into onCompleteListener

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an ArrayList of product that has to be filled with some data like quantity, name , expiration and id.

I used two firebase queries because I need to get the "wishlist" productids from the collection wishlist for the user, and then retrieve the product data from the collection "annuncio" for every wishlisted product.

The code seems working, when I try to fill the "prod" ArrayList I see that the data are coming in from the debugger but once I check prod after the for it looks like the array list is empty.

Here's the code of the fragment:

```
public class FavouriteAdvertisement extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object2";
    public RecyclerView recyclerView ;
    private ArrayList<Product> products;


    // creates the view and calls the function favouriteProductsToRecycleview to load the cards
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourite, container, false);
        products  = new ArrayList<Product>();
       favouriteProductsToRecycleview(root,products);
        return root;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }

    private void favouriteProductsToRecycleview(View v, ArrayList<Product>prod) {

        FirebaseFirestore db;
        FirebaseAuth auth;
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        //first query that gets every favourite item of the user

        Task<QuerySnapshot> documenti = db.collection("watchlist")
                .whereEqualTo("User", auth.getUid())
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                                //second query that uses the favourite items to retrieve their data

                                FirebaseFirestore db2 = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                                DocumentReference doc = db2.collection("annuncio")
                                        .document(Objects.requireNonNull(document.getString("Product")));
                                doc.get()
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                                DocumentSnapshot doc2;
                                                if (task.getResult().exists()) {
                                                    doc2 = task.getResult();
                                                } else {
                                                    return;
                                                }
                                                doc2 = task.getResult();
                                                prod.add(new Product(doc2.getString("name"),
                                                        doc2.getString("quantity"),
                                                        doc2.getString("expiration"),
                                                        doc2.getString("UId"),
                                                        doc2.getId()));
                                            }
                                            //until here prod fills correctly , but when it goes to the recycle view it's empty??? TODO
                                        });
                            }

                                recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.result_favourite);
                                MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(v.getContext(), prod);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext()));
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

here's myAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {
    private ArrayList< Product> products;
    Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context ct , ArrayList<Product> prodotti){

        products=prodotti;
        context=ct;


    }

        // here i create my card
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_card,parent,false);
        return  new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    // here i add information to my card
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.name.setText(products.get(position).getName());
      holder.quantity.setText(products.get(position).getQuantity());
      holder.expire.setText(products.get(position).getExpiration());
      holder.userid.setText(products.get(position).getUserId());
      holder.productId =products.get(position).getProduct();

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return products.size();
    }


// here i declare what are the attributes of the card and how it behaves
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView name,quantity,expire,userid;
        Button  goToUser;
        FloatingActionButton addToFavorite;
        String productId;
       public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
           expire = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productexpire);
           name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productname);
           quantity =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.productquantity);
           userid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productauthor);

           addToFavorite = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_to_fav_btn);
           addToFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                   Date date = new Date();
                   SimpleDateFormat ft =
                           new SimpleDateFormat ("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");

                   Map<String, Object> prod = new HashMap<>();
                   prod.put("User",userid.getText());
                   prod.put("Product",productId);
                   prod.put("date",ft.format(date));

                   db.collection("watchlist")
                           .document()
                           .set(prod, SetOptions.merge())
                           .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                   Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"added to favourites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                               }
                           })
                   .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                           Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"cannot add to favourites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   });

               }
           });

           goToUser =itemView.findViewById(R.id.btngotouser);
           goToUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"bla",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   UserFragment userFragment = new UserFragment();
                   FragmentManager fragmentManager = new FragmentManager(){} ;
                   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.list_home,userFragment);
               }
           });



       }
   }

}
```

and my Product object

```
public class Product {
    private String Name;
    private String Quantity;
    private String Expiration;
    private String UserId;
    private String product;


    public Product(String name, String quantity, String expiration,String Uid, String productId) {
        Name = name;
        Quantity = quantity;
        Expiration = expiration;
        UserId = Uid;
        product = productId;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return UserId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        UserId = userId;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return Quantity;
    }

    public String getExpiration() {
        return Expiration;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void setExpiration(String expiration) {
        Expiration = expiration;

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a "wild "guess, but could it be that the `RecyclerView` instantiation gets called before the listener does anything?

Comment: yes it could be but wherever i put the recycle view it always get an empty array list

Answer (score 0):

I would remove "prod" in the Fragment as you already have access to the products variable

Also these 2 lines should be in onViewCreated

```
products  = new ArrayList<Product>();

favouriteProductsToRecycleview(root,products);
```

If it's still the same afterwards  really check what is added before adding it, because ArrayList probably isn't the source of the error

Comment: i already tried with the  removed parameter , that was just a try , i think the problem has something to do with the second db search because i use this card in another place with a  simple query and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Your onclicklistener needs to be written in the onbindviewholder.That is where your recycler view is loaded.The view holder is just a class to hold the view of the recycler view.

```
       addToFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
               Date date = new Date();
               SimpleDateFormat ft =
                       new SimpleDateFormat ("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");

               Map<String, Object> prod = new HashMap<>();
               prod.put("User",userid.getText());
               prod.put("Product",productId);
               prod.put("date",ft.format(date));

               db.collection("watchlist")
                       .document()
                       .set(prod, SetOptions.merge())
                       .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                               Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"added to favourites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                           }
                       })
               .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                       Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"cannot add to favourites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               });

           }
       });
```

Comment: i have put it in there beacuse that's the constructor of the card , just for ease of reading , and it doeasn't change anything , works just fine